# Display only relevant information in a moderator's history page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools

When you visit `site.com/admin/history/<moderator's-user-id>`, it displays a "history" of actions taken by the moderator. Here's a small snippet from my history on [gardening.se].

[image: Image of current history]

This is not at all helpful because it is merely listing actions for which I have the necessary reputation to do anywhere on the site, irrespective of mod status. Also, the `2xAdded Comment` is incorrect, because I have not commented at all on that post.

Now the reason why these posts are shown in the mod history page is because I did take a mod-only action, which is that of deleting comments. This is something I routinely do to clean up (move information from comments to answers/questions) and reduce chatter. But there is no indication of this!

Can we please change the information to only reflect the action that was taken as a result of our mod privileges?

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think I want only the mod-only actions. For example, if a question was flagged as off-topic, and I agreed that it was off-topic, but I decided to edit it rather than close, then I would prefer for my edit to show up on that page.

I don't think there is too much information on that page. Sure, some of it is spurious¹, but it doesn't cause any harm.

¹ 
<sub>For example, if one of my posts is flagged, I see “2×moderator edits user”. Because I edited my profile twice… Technically incorrect (this is the number of times I've edited my profile, as a normal user), but not a big deal.</sub>

Comment: Well, for flagged posts I certainly don't mind something like `Moderator dismisses flags, Edit Body, Edit Title,...` I don't really care if all the spurious info is shown _if_ the actual mod-action is also indicated, which in this case would be `NxDeleted Comments`, where `N` is the number of nuked comments.